# updatepanel never triggers the OnSelectedIndexChanged function when I use fullcalendar

Tags: updatepanel, fullcalendar

I want to develop a fullcalendar based web, and all goes well until I met this question, I use a jQuery dialog when fullcalendar day click,and I plan to use updatepanel to make my dropdownlist linkage in jQuery dialog. But I found the OnSelectedIndexChanged function never triggered. I found when I add this code `style="display:block"`on the `<div>`, all code works well, when I use the jQuery dialog, the updatepanel never triggers the OnSelectedIndexChanged function.

So, is it means that I cannot use the updatepanel in the jQuery dialog?